# Issue in a text-based game (variables and displaying them)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a text-based game, now I have a problem. I declared "a "(amount of apples) as 0. Then I created a button which added 1 to "a". Then I tried displayed the amount of apples on screen (tkinter). Now when I click the button which adds +1 to "a" it doesnt update on screen. Help?

[Screenshot of code](https://gyazo.com/bf2af295033d8648d42f37e087766d8b)

Comment: please, add your code in text format instead of image

Comment: Do *not* post images of code, and least of all, do not post *links to images* of code. Post the code in the question itself as *formatted text*.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)